# Changing numpy array to dataframe and merge two dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How I can change two numpy array and dataframe and merge them ?

I have:

```
X

array([1461, 1462, 1463, ..., 2917, 2918, 2919])
```

and

```
y_test_pred

array([272229.457876  , 256423.56032314, 281508.5907379 , ...,
       223281.89247352, 223185.78377167, 229313.97269616])
```

My goal is to make following format:

```
Id,SalePrice

1461,169000.1

1462,187724.1233

1463,175221
```

etc.

Many thanks,

Dataleon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just construct a dataframe with `concat`:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(X), pd.Series(y_test_pred)], axis=1).rename({0:  'Id', 1: 'SalePrice'}, axis=1)
```

Comment: I got this error:ValueError: arrays must all be same length